# Can't authenticate to exceed Github api rate limit in React App

Tags: javascript, api, github-api

I'm trying to axios.get repos from most popular users on Github.
The problem is I can't get past rate limit using OAuth token.
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jE4IX.png)

```
const headers = {
"Authorization" : `token ${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}`,
'User-Agent': 'kiknalex'}

const userRepos = (reposUrl) => {
const request = axios.get(reposUrl);
return request.then(response => response.data, {
    "headers": headers
})}
```

But it gives me this error
[Response Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fx15a.png)

I've also tried to authenticate using curl,but it didn't work.
How do I authenticate with OAuth token properly, or is there any other way to make rate limit higher.

Comment: Looks like the API you are using has a limit of 60 request for some time interval. Meaning once you have used your 60 request they block you for X ammout of time. [This](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/resources-in-the-rest-api#rate-limiting) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Update:
Apparently I "sent" headers in the response, it should be in get request.